# Javascript largest number that can be made with the same digits

Tags: javascript

I am working on a problem that can do the following: -

This function takes a number and returns the largest number that can be made with the same digits.
E.g. if num is 23, the function should return 32.

E.g. if num is 9, the function should return 9.

E.g. if num is 581 the function should return 851.

```
function largestNumber(num) {

    var num = String(num).split().sort().reverse().join('')

    return Number(num)
  }
```

Comment: you used split() instead it should be split('').
`var num = String(num).split('').sort().reverse().join('')`. You managed to pass the first 2 tests because the input and output are same.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your `split()` call and don't redeclare `num`:

```
num = String(num).split('').sort().reverse().join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to change your `split()` to `split('')` as commented.
2. you don't need to instantiate a new variable you can have your code in the return statement itself.

`return Number(String(num).split('').sort().reverse().join(''));`

Answer (score 0):

Answer: -

```
function largestNumber(num) {
    num = String(num).split('').sort().reverse().join('');
    return Number(num);
}
```

This passes all my tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
num = String(num).split('').sort().reverse().join('');
```

Basically it's sorting the digits from smallest to biggest, then reverses it to get biggest to smallest, and turns it into a string by joining it with a connector. *Well, there isn't really a connector*

But for people who don't understand:

```
num = String(num).split('');
var exArray = num;
var a = (i+1)%num.length
//Sorting
for(var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) if(Number(num[i])>Number(num[a])){var x=i;num[i]=a;num[a]=x;}
return num.join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this,

```
var num = 2134;
var largestNum = parseInt(num.toString().split('').sort().reverse().join(''))
```

Output : largestNum = 4321